# Webstorm debug session - Variables view

Tags: debugging, webstorm

When I am debugging from the IDE using the Chrome addin
[image][image]
It starts up and I can set breakpoints and edit the code live which is really great, but when I try to inspect the current state using the Variables view, I can't see all of the object members.  For example, if I debug using the Chrome Developer Tools I see...
[image]
...I have live access to the entire object structure.
But in Webstorm I can only see this...
[image]
It seems like it only works for user defined properties and the `__proto__` object.  Is this the case or is there a setting somewhere to enable this?  There is nothing I can find in the Webstorm documentation indicating that this is a limitation of the tool...

I just want to know if this is a limitation or not.

Just in case the pics are not clear, here are the pics of the document node in the WS IDE, Watches window...

[image]
And here is what I expect to see and what I do see in the Chrome Dev tools...
[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? All I can see is __proto__ and not the actual contents of the object.

Comment: I asked in the online help forum what was the design: what am I supposed to see? But they refused to give a direct answer, they told me to contact the tech team. I referred them to this SO question in case they were unclear what I was asking but still, all I got was a blank stare. I tried to continue the conversation by saying that I didn't want to bother the tech team until I had confirmation about what I was supposed to be seeing but that question got tagged as spam as did every other attempt to further the conversation. Great product but very strange customer support experience.